# How to add the values ​of several fields in sql and create one from that sum using Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am studying Django and SQL and I have proposed to create a social network in which I can add all the reactions of a publication and add it to a new field where they are all added.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):

   # User
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   post = models.TextField(max_length=500000)

   # Data
   comments = models.IntegerField()
   reactions = models.IntegerField()

   ## Reaction Data
   like = models.IntegerField()
   love = models.IntegerField()
   wow = models.IntegerField()
   sad = models.IntegerField()
   angry = models.IntegerField()
```

That is the model of publications, there is a field called reactions, and that will be the sum of all the reactions that publication has acquired. How can I create that sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such architecture will be a little wrong.

```
from project_name import settings 

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()

    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
    love = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='post_loves')
    # ... another reactions 

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

> settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is your User

After that you will then be able to not only know the number of reactions, but also to identify users

To count users:

> post = Post.objects.create(author=..., ...)   # create post
>
> queryset = post.likes # will return users id, who liked post
>
> queryset.count() # will return number of users